# Text in pygame thats formatted as a paragraph?

Tags: python, text, pygame

Trying to write a pygame program, but I can't seem to figure out how to let pygame format text as a paragraph without third party modules. For example, I want:

```
"Hello World, how are you doing today? I'm fine actually, thank you."
```

to be more along the lines of:

```
"Hello World, how are
 you doing today? I'm
fine actually, thank you."
```

Here is my code:

```
def instructions(text):
    pressKey, pressRect = makeText('Last Block is a survival game. Every ten lines that you clear will shorten the screen, clear as many lines as possible before you run out of space!', smallFont, bgColor)
    pressRect.center = (int(windowWidth/ 2), int(windowHeight / 2) + 100)
    displaySurf.blit(pressKey, pressRect)
    while press() == None:
        pygame.display.update()
```

and the `makeText` function:

```
def makeText(text, font, color):
    surf = font.render(text, True, color)
    return surf, surf.get_rect()
```

So that pygame can divide the long line of text up into sections of x words each and format it to look somewhat like a paragraph. Right now, I'm using numerous surface objects and blits to make it look like this which seems tedious. Any other ways to achieve the effect?

Comment: By "outside modules", do you mean 3rd-party modules or every module that isn't `pygame`?  In other words, are you fine with using the built-in modules?  Because, if so, you may be interested in the built-in [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module.

Comment: 3rd party = outside. If possible, could you quickly explain the `textwrap` module?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want some code to display text in a multiline paragraph. If so, I used the code here: http://www.pygame.org/pcr/text_rect/index.php

Doesn't need any additional modules.The method takes the following parameters:

```
def render_textrect(string, font, rect, text_color, background_color, justification=0):
    """Returns a surface containing the passed text string, reformatted
    to fit within the given rect, word-wrapping as necessary. The text
    will be anti-aliased.

    Takes the following arguments:

    string - the text you wish to render. \n begins a new line.
    font - a Font object
    rect - a rectstyle giving the size of the surface requested.
    text_color - a three-byte tuple of the rgb value of the
                 text color. ex (0, 0, 0) = BLACK
    background_color - a three-byte tuple of the rgb value of the surface.
    justification - 0 (default) left-justified
                    1 horizontally centered
                    2 right-justified

    Returns the following values:

    Success - a surface object with the text rendered onto it.
    Failure - raises a TextRectException if the text won't fit onto the surface.
    """
```

Sorry for posting again - clicked community wiki by mistake.

Comment: What is the `recttype` parameter?

Comment: Not sure where you're getting `recttype` from. I've updated the answer to show what arguments you need to pass. If you're referring to `rect` this is just a pygame.Rect object (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) which is basically the size of the area you want your text to be in.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for the functionality offered by [`textwrap.fill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill):

```
from textwrap import fill
mystr = "Hello World, how are you doing today? I'm fine actually, thank you."
print(fill(mystr, 20))
print()
print(fill(mystr, 40))
print()
print(fill(mystr, 10))
```

Output:

```
Hello World, how are
you doing today? I'm
fine actually, thank
you.

Hello World, how are you doing today?
I'm fine actually, thank you.

Hello
World, how
are you
doing
today? I'm
fine
actually,
thank you.
```

The first argument to `textwrap.fill` is the string that you want to break up.  The second is the maximum length of the lines (in characters).

Comment: Hi, I tried this within my function that creates the `pygame` text objects. Instead of splitting the lines, the `fill` created boxes between them. I'll edit my question to include the complete function. I don't believe I am using strings within pygame, instead it is being passed as another parameter to the function.